# install .net application online

Tags: .net, winforms, installation

I have a windows form application. I want to enable the users to visit url (a website) and then click the Install Button on the website. Clicking this button should install the application on their computer. I hope I made myself clear. Any help would be appreciated.

**I do not want a clickOnce installation or MSI package to be available online for download**

Comment: When you googled this, did you really not come across [ClickOnce Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(v=vs.80).aspx)?

Comment: I am aware of clickonce installations, but i don not want that. I would prefer it to be a normal software package. Click Once apps are isolated, and installed per user, I want my application to be installed like any other application installed using Advanced Installer or MSI packages.

Comment: Then add that as information to your question. How was I to know you didn't want ClickOnce? =) Then you're pretty much down to providing an MSI that the user has to download and execute, or a ZIP package. As already suggested.

Comment: I've deleted my answer per your edit. However, it would be helpful if you explained why those two choices are inadequate.

Comment: Distributing MSI or ZIP is an easy thing to do. What I want is that the user downloading my project should not be able to download the files but install only.

Comment: @SamarthAgarwal: it's unclear what is the issue with ClickOnce. Your specific case is handled by CLickOnce, which has been designed for this scenario. Moreover, for security issue, don't expect to find a way to fire a msi package with one click, unless you control the computer (some intranet scenario are possible).

Comment: I deleted my last comment, I was not specific.
See, we create a msi package or advanced installer package/windows installer package that installs our app. I want a simple solution, to install files in the same manner but from the internet.

Comment: To run the script have to be able to read the script.  In IIS cannot give execute permission without read permission.   Your might get there with Right Management Service.   Why do you not want them to be able to download?

Answer (score 0):

go to project properties -> publish -> publish wizard -> from a website and go on

Comment: I guess that will create a ClickOnce installation.